# Ivy/APL primes algorithm

Tags: prime-numbers

The Google’s Ivy interpreter is a APL-like math language.
This is an example of first N primes numbers algorithm in Ivy/APL

```
op primes N = (not T in T o.* T) sel T = 1 drop iota N
```

Could someone describe the notation for the primes algorithm here?

Ivy/APL doc is [here](https://godoc.org/robpike.io/ivy).

Comment: This isn't "APL-like", it's almost readable. But it's certainly not a mathematical question.

Comment: You are right agreed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be directly translated to APL from the vocabularies provided in the doc.

```
{(~T∊T∘.×T)/T←1↓⍳⍵}
```

someone who have learned the notation of APL might already figured it out, but since APL isn't very popular, here's an attempt of explanation:

it means assign T with dropping first element of iota N, which is a sequence of numbers 2..N, then filtering out those that belongs to `T∘.×T that is the outer product, what been left are the primes.